# How can I cleanup iPad app from the Device?

Tags: ios

I deployed my app with images for the retina display onto my iPad. Those images are too big. So I want to try using normal size image. I removed my retina display images from the project. I did a cleanup and deployed the app onto my iPad. I still see the retina display image on the device. I am using cocos2d. So the retina display image files are named sprite-hd.png.

I will try testing with sprite@2x.png format. I think even after the app is deleted (long touch and then touch little x icon), the app's resources are still the in the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the app from the device, clean targets in Xcode (command-shift-k) and run again and it should work fine.